# How can I escase string in whereRaw?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 I use whereRaw in code like :

```
 $query->whereRaw( 'item.day ' . $sign . "'".$filter_day."' " );
```

But I need to escape it.
Function mysql_real_escape_string is absolute now...
What can I use here ? I work with mysql8 now, but I prefer decision for different db on laravel side.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give me the possible values of `$sign`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the Laravel documentation thoroughly: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-methods

You can escape the string using `?` as the link I given above.

```
$query->whereRaw( 'item.day ' . $sign . ' ?', [$filter_day]);
```

You must NOT escape the operator `$sign` because its an MYSQL operator.
And also you must make sure that you properly check/sanitize `$sign` to avoid SQL injection. E.g.

```
if (in_array($sign, ['=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=', '<>'])) {
    $query->whereRaw( 'item.day ' . $sign . ' ?', [$filter_day]);
}
```